# Bootstrap Javascript error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .bs-docs-container [href=#]

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I inherited this project built in Jekyll with Bootstrap CSS. The Javascript console keeps indicating the following error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .bs-docs-container [href=#]
```

Pretty sure this js is causing the error:

```
a(".bs-docs-container [href=#]").click(function(a){
    a.preventDefault()
})
```

But it's been a long time since I've done any javascript and I am not sure how to debug this. This looks like it is simply canceling the event if the ` when it is within a div referencing .bs-docs-container.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is that selector intended to do? I think the problem is that attribute selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a(".bs-docs-container [href='#']").click(function(a){
    a.preventDefault()
})
```

Mind the single quotes around the hash

Answer (score 1):

You need to quot hash mark

```
a(".bs-docs-container [href='#']")
```